# addEventListener() not working on list of elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener, removechild

I have an array of paragraph elements. When each `<p>` is clicked on I want that element removed from the DOM. The code I've written only works when an element is specified by its id. I've tried using the `this` keyword, as well as looping through the elements without any success as the code below shows.

What am I doing wrong here ? How can I overcome it ?

```
<div class="section" id='section2'>
<a name="section-two" href="#top">Section Two</a>

        <p id='tester'>Text here <span><img src='images/remove.png' height='20px'/></span></p>
        <p>Text here. <span><img src='images/remove.png' width='20px'/></span></p>
        <p>Text here. <span><img src='images/remove.png' height='20px'/></span></p>
        <p>Text here. <span><img src='images/remove.png' height='20px'/></span></p>
    </div>

var section2 = document.getElementById('section2').getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < section2.length; i++) {

  section2[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  section2[i].parentNode.removeChild(section2[i]);
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd attach a listener to the parent, instead of the children, and check what was clicked. That's a bit more efficient than attaching n-listeners, especially on items you'd remove from the DOM anyway.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('section2');

parent.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'P') {
        parent.removeChild(event.target);
    }
}, false);
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dw4s/1/) to illustrate how I would go on about doing something like that.

For completeness sake:
The code you've written won't also work, because you're referencing `i` variable in a callback. In your case, when the callback would be executed, `i` would always be equal to the its last value assigned by the loop. You'd need to reassign `i` to a local variable in the callback to do that (that way you'd have a 'copy' and not a reference). Also if you care for IE lt 8 you'd have to rewrite that to use legacy IE `attachEvent` api, but I assumed (based on nothing in particular) that you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks, as an extension to the answer above. If I wanted to make the image tags the only clickable area that deletes its parent paragraph tag, how would I go about that ?

Comment: You'd filter out different event target by tag name and then reference its parent e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/48jkL/

Answer (score 1):

```
var section2 = document.getElementById('section2').getElementsByTagName('p');
alert(section2.length)
for(var i = 0; i < section2.length; i++) {

  section2[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}, false);
}
```

replace section2[i] by this inside callback function,

because of javascript closure i will be equal to section2.length,

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v7FvW/1/